# Regex replace any number of matches at the start of the line

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I have text with this structure:

```
1.  Text1
2.  Text 2. It has a number with a dot.
3.  1.   Text31
```

I want to get this text:

```
# Text1
# Text 2. It has a number with a dot. (notice that this number did not get replaced)
## Text31
```

I tried doing the following but it does not work

```
var pattern = @"^(\s*\d+\.\s*)+";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(str, pattern, "#", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Basically, it should start matching at the start of every line and replace every matched group with # symbol. Currently, if more than one group is matched, everything is replaced by a single # symbol. Pattern I am using is probably incorrect, can anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: The pattern looks for multiple occurences of the pattern and therefore the Replace replaces all occurences that were found with one "#". You could use a loop to iterate over a simpler version of the regex like "^#*(\s*\d+\.\s*)" and replace it every time. That would cost a bit of CPU but get you what you want.

Comment: Try `(?:\G|^)\s*\d+\.` to replace with `#`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:\G|^)\s*\d+\.
```

It matches the start of string or the end of the previous successful match or start of a line, and then zero or more whitespaces, one or more digits and a dot.

**Details**

- `(?:\G|^)` - start of string or end of the previous match (`\G`) or the start of a line (`^`)
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces if you want to only match horizontal whitespaces to avoid overflowing to the next lie(s) replace with `[\s-[\r\n]]*` or `[\p{Zs}\t]*`)
- `\d+` - one or more digits (to match only ASCII digits, replace with `[0-9]+` or pass the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option to the Regex constructor)
- `\.` - a dot.

The `RegexOptions.Multiline` option must be passed to the Regex constructor to make `^` match the start of a line. Or add an inline version of the anchor, `(?m)`, at the start of the pattern.

For more details about `\G` anchor, see [**Continuing at The End of The Previous Match**](http://regular-expressions.info/continue.html?wlr=1).

See the [RegexStorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cG%7c%5e%29%5cs*%5cd%2b%5c.&i=1.+Text1+%0d%0a2.+Text+2.+%0d%0a3.+1.+Text31&r=%23&o=m).

Comment: Seems to work. Could you explain the "?:\G" part or just provide some link for reference?

Comment: I am on a mobile and it takes time to write an answer. I will be adding details. I was trying to post this comment dozens of times, the connection is awful here.

Comment: It seens to me you could also use a lookbehind based solution here: `(?<=^(?:\s*\d+\.)*)\s*\d+\.`. However, it is much longer and less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(?<![a-z].*)\s*\d+\.
```

It looks for a sequence of digits `\d+` followed by a dot `\.` preceded by any number of white space characters `\s*`. This, in turn, **must not** be preceded by a letter on the line, checked by a negative look-behind `(?<![a-z].*)` in the beginning of the regex.

[Here at RegEx Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5ba-z%5d.*%29%5cs*%5cd%2b%5c.&i=1.++Text1%0d%0a2.++Text+2.+It+has+a+number+with+a+dot.%0d%0a3.++1.+++Text31).

Comment: My example was not clear enough. I have updated it and to show why your regex also matches what I don't need.

Comment: OK. Edited to work. But when Wiktors in the game, I fold. About `\G` - see [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html).